# Preload AJAX images/content in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, preload

I'm currently using AJAX to load my Wordpress posts into the Index page once the title is clicked—like an accordion. The problem is, most of the posts contain lots of large images and it's taking a long time for them to show once the AJAX function has run and all you see are the image captions stacked up before the images start loading.

Is there a way that I can preload the content that is being added by AJAX, so when the user clicks the title the images load super quick?

Below is the AJAX code I am using. All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
        $("a.exhibitionInformation").on("click", function(event) {

        var exhibitionContainer = $(this).parent(".exhibition");
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var doc = $(this).next(".exhibitionDocuments");
        var title = convertToSlug($(this).text().split("\n")[1]);
        var slug = $(this).attr("data-slug");
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");

        if($(doc).is(':not(:hidden)')) {
            $(doc).slideToggle();
        } else {            


            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    var content = $(data).find(".single-document");                 
                    $(doc).append(content).slideToggle(300);                    
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: exhibitionContainer.offset().top - 26 });
                    window.location.hash = slug;
                }           
            });

        }

        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: There are many ways to preload images. You can do a search for that itself. You can call the ajax function when the page loads, rather than on click. then save the `data` to a variable. And when the user clicks the anchor you defined, then you can append the content to the `.single-document`

Comment: In the same spirit, when the above is retrieved, I'm assuming it's an html string, then you can do a search in it for img and src and preload those.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon. Thanks for the quick replies. These sounds like good ideas although I'm not sure how to implement them. Is it possible to let me know how I can do this? Thank you!

Comment: Method 2 starts you off: https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: But in terms of structure, move the `$.ajax` function out of the `.on('click'`, and make it its own function elsewhere in the code, for example, call it when the page is run. Then the `success: function` should  save data to a variable for later availability (so you can do the `.append` once the user clicks. Also in the `success` function you should scan the string which comes back and pull out all images.

But it seems that you are pulling the url out of the link clicked, so if you have lots of these on the page, you may want to consider only preloading the first few.